# java calling main method array argument (easy but confusing)

Tags: java, recursion

I wanted to call the code in the main method, but it seems like it doesn't really work.

```
public class RecursiveSelectionSort {

public static void sort(double [] list){


    sort(list, 0, list.length -1);
}
public static void sort(double [] list, int low, int high){
    if (low < high){
        int indexOfMin = low;
        double min = list[low];
        for(int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++){
            if(list[i]< min){
                min = list[i];
                indexOfMin = i;
            }
        }
        list[indexOfMin] = list[low];
        list[low] = min;

        sort(list, low + 1, high);
    }
}
public static void main(String [] args){
    double [] list = {3.0,4.0,1.0};//I tried but it doesn't work
    System.out.print(sort(list));//it doesn't go to sort(list);
}
}
```

I was wondering if I can call it. It seems easy, but really confusing.

Comment: What makes you think `sort` isn't called? Have you tried tracing?

Comment: @BenMinchanJun you need to accept one answer if you feel you are satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` is a `void` method, you can't print its result. Try `sort`ing first and *then* printing the list separately.

Answer (score 5):

The method `sort` returns `void`, but you're trying to pass its result into `print`. Try this instead:

```
double [] list = {3.0,4.0,1.0};
sort(list);
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list));
```

Notice I also used the utility method [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29), which is necessary because arrays themselves don't override `toString` to show their contents.

Answer (score 0):

The `println` function doesn't support `void` parameters. IT expects some **non void** object as input. but your sort function returns **nothing**. That's why it is not printing.

Comment: What's a "void parameter"? I don't think you _can_ expect a void parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Mainn {

    public static void sort(double [] list){
            //change 1
        System.out.println("Inside sort");
        sort(list, 0, list.length -1);
    }
    public static void sort(double [] list, int low, int high){
        if (low < high){
            int indexOfMin = low;
            double min = list[low];
            for(int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++){
                if(list[i]< min){
                    min = list[i];
                    indexOfMin = i;
                }
            }
            list[indexOfMin] = list[low];
            list[low] = min;

            sort(list, low + 1, high);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        double [] list = {3.0,4.0,1.0};//I tried but it doesn't work

        //change 2
        sort(list);
        //return type of sort was void

        //print sorted list here
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the result should be printed from within `sort`.

Comment: I don't think `sort` should print _anything_.

Comment: change 1 is just to demonstrate that the control is going inside sort() but not required

Comment: just kept the sysout there to clear @Ben's doubt that sort is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class RecursiveSelectionSort {

    public static double[] sort(double [] list){
    return sort(list, 0, list.length -1);
    }
    public static double[] sort(double [] list, int low, int high){
        if (low < high){
            int indexOfMin = low;
            double min = list[low];
            for(int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++){
                if(list[i]< min){
                    min = list[i];
                    indexOfMin = i;
                }
            }
            list[indexOfMin] = list[low];
            list[low] = min;
            return sort(list, low + 1, high);
        }
            else return list;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        double [] list = {3.0,4.0,1.0};
        list = sort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
}
```